# Use TypeScript lib.core.d.ts instead of lib.d.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript1.4

It seems the TypeScript compiler always includes `lib.d.ts` or `lib.es6.d.ts` (depending on the compiler target).

In our application we have a `WebSocket` class that is already defined in `lib.d.ts`. We're running our application under Node.js and not in a web browser, so we actually don't need all of the definitions from `lib.d.ts`. Instead `lib.core.d.ts` would be sufficient for us (and would solve the `WebSocket` conflict of course).

Is it possible to tell the TypeScript compiler which global type definition file to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`--noLib` compiler option](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler%20Options) to exclude `lib.d.ts` and then add reference to `lib.core.d.ts` in your source files.

Equivalent for `tsconfig.json` would be `"noLib": true`.

If you only need Node.js definitions, you can also use the [`Definitely Typed one`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use lib like core-js. which has all the required polyfils for ES6. Note: you will also will need to add the core-js tsd file to your tsds.

Hope it helps.